# Possible mistake in Lancaster’s QFT pg 351?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

[image]

In QFT for the gifted amateur by Lancaster pg 350, the matrix element for bhabha scattering is calculated. The spinor for an incoming electron is shown as $u(p) = (0,0,1,0)$ but on the next page when multiplying it with a gamma matrix, it is written as $(0,0,0,-1)$. Is this a mistake? Why does the spinor change for $u(p)$?

Comment: This appears to be an obvious typo (confusing u and v), i.e. the l.h.s. there should just be something like $\bar v \gamma^\mu v$ and not $u$. Do you have any reason to believe it's not typo?

Comment: Because what is considered is bhabha scattering, which means that there should be a $u$ in the matrix element represented in incoming electron

Comment: $\bar{v} \gamma^\mu v$ corresponds to the positron current. The Bhabha amplitude is composed of the positron and electron currents ($\bar{v} \gamma^\mu v$ and $\bar{u} \gamma^\mu u$). There is no $\bar{v} \gamma^\mu u$ term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a typo in the matrix notation. This chapter is looking at an annihilation-creation Bhabha process (s-channel). Here, the vertices are $\bar{v}(p')\gamma^{\mu}u(p)$ and $\bar{u}(k)\gamma^{\mu}v(k')$, so the notation for the vertex is correct (unlike suggested in the comments). It seems to be that the explicit expanded notation has a typo instead, and that it should be
$$\bar{v}(p')\gamma^{\mu}u(p)=2E(0, 0, 0, -1)\left(\begin{matrix}
\bar{\sigma}^{\mu} & 0 \\
0 & \sigma^{\mu} \\
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)=-2E\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 1 \\ i \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right).$$

You can verify this by calculating the product explicitly (taking $\sigma^{\mu}$ and $\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}$ to be $\sigma^0 = I, \pm\sigma^1, \pm\sigma^2, \pm\sigma^3$ in turn, and summing over all other indices), and you will obtain the correct result.

Comment: Just figured this out, but still thank you for your answer!

Comment: Ooh, but another question. The book says the positron is left handed. If that is true then shouldn’t the nonzero component of the anti spinor be in the first 2 entries instead of the last two?

Comment: The version I have says its right-handed.

Comment: Are you sure? Then that would be bhabha scattering with right handed electron and right handed positron, but they have to have opposite handedness. “We will collide the electron with a left handed positron”

Comment: I believe you are using an outdated version of the book. There is a newer edition from 2018 with significant changes to this section (here both electron and positron are right-handed)